# Javascript `typeof` validation issue

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm starting to learn OOP in JS and I came across this issue where my `alert()` will not trigger when `validateString` returns false. I try `personOne.setFirstName('');` but the `alert()` does not trigger.

```
//define Name class 
function Name () {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.middleName = '';
    this.details = {
        eyeColor: '',
        hairColor: ''
    }
};

var validateString = function(p) {
    return typeof p != "undefined" && $.trim(p).length;
};

//begin Name methods
Name.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.middleName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};
Name.prototype.setFirstName = function(p) {
    if (validateString) {
        this.firstName = p;
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a valid first name.');
    }
};
Name.prototype.setLastName = function(p) {
    if (validateString) {
        this.lastName = p;
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a valid last name.');
    }
};
Name.prototype.setMiddleName = function(p) {
    if (validateString) {
        this.middleName = p;
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a valid middle name.');
    }
};
Name.prototype.setHairColor = function(p) {
    this.details.hairColor = p;
};
Name.prototype.setEyeColor = function(p) {
    this.details.eyeColor = p;
};

//end Name methods

var personOne = new Name();
personOne.setFirstName('John');
personOne.setLastName('Doe');
personOne.setMiddleName('Barry');
personOne.setEyeColor('Brown');
personOne.setHairColor('Black');
document.write(personOne.getFullName());
document.write(personOne.details.eyeColor);
document.write(personOne.details.hairColor);
```

Comment: Just a note: you probably should define `validateString()` as a static `Name` method; at the moment it is not part of the class even though it is required by many of the `Name` methods.

Comment: @DavidJohnWelsh Actually it's fine the way it is when he uses the module pattern :)

Comment: @Jack What is the "module pattern?" I'm new around here :)

Comment: @Etcher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691300/why-does-module-pattern-create-a-singleton/10722623#10722623

Comment: I'm not old around here but not exactly new around here (I'm middle-aged around here...?) and *I* don't understand, either. I'm sure I'm just being dim (happens a lot :-D), but how is the module pattern relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to `validateString`.

```
if (validateString(p)) {
  //etc
}
```

**EDIT:**
... and also, as @potench mentioned, the reason the `if` statement was evaluated as `true` is because this:

```
if (myFunc) {
  //blah
}
```

means "if `myFunc` exists as a defined variable". In this case it's the same as `if (3)` or `if (true)`.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now, such a newbie mistake.

Comment: The alert does not trigger because `validateString` is truthy (it's defined as a function so `if(validateString)` passes since validateString is not null, 0, or undefined.

Comment: David you may want to edit your answer to reflect why the `alert` is not firing (because `if(validateString)...` is truthy)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `validateString` in this case. Consider

```
Name.prototype.setFirstName = function(p) {
  this.firstName = p || alert('please enter a first name');
}
```

This is called a [short circuit boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If no parameter is supplied, or the parameter is an empty string, the alert will be triggered and `this.firstName  will be undefined. If you need to check te length of`p`, use:

```
Name.prototype.setFirstName = function(p) {
  this.firstName = (p && p.trim().length) || alert('please enter a first name');
}
```

Comment: yes, but if in the future he wants to expand the validation routine (only allow certain characters or whatever), he will need a separate method to deal with it. I think since the OP is specifically trying to learn an OOP way of doing things, compartmentalizing everything is a good idea.